# mapViewWillStartLoadingMap not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

Hey guys Im trying to show the activity indicator when the map is loading.

```
- (void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES
    NSLog(@"map started loading);
}
```

I tried using above method, but it never gets called.
Whenever i zoom in or out the map tiles will start loading, however this method is not called.

Comment: @Mike: It's Objective-C.  @user774150: Have you set the map view's delegate property?

Comment: @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate,  MKReverseGeocoderDelegate>

this is my .h file, is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declaring that your class implements the protocol is not enough.  That just helps the compiler generate warnings or errors about missing or incorrect method implementations.

You have to actually set the `delegate` property of the map view to that class instance.

If the map view has been created in IB then right-click on the map view and connect the delegate property to File's Owner.

If the map view is created in code, then in `viewDidLoad`, add a line like:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

If you've done all this and the method still isn't getting called, it's also possible that the regions your are viewing are already cached locally and don't need re-loading.  Try moving to a region or zooming in deep somewhere you've never been.

Comment: thanks. stupid me. the delegate is not connected. only the IBOutlet is connected.